# What is the best way to handle toolbars in an iPad app that only appear on touch and disappear after no activity?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a toolbar in a regular UIView (not uiwebview) that I only want to fade in when the user taps on the screen. Then after some period of inactivity it would be great if it faded out. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You can use NSTimer for showing and after 5 seconds hiding the toolbar with animation

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase my question to ask, "what is the best way to detect activity and inactivity?"

Answer (score 0):

Use an [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i) then provide [animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) to show the toolbar hiding.

Comment: Perhaps I need a better gesture recognizer. If the user keeps his finger down on the surface how will I know?

Comment: Listen for begin touches at a global enough level to meet your requirements and set a BOOL that user is touching the screen. Then listend for end or cancel touches and set that BOOL to NO and then start your timer. By global enough I mean if the view controller is full screen then just capture touch events in that view controller (as opposed to being contained in a UIInavigationController, tab bar or splitview)